# How pure binary code works fine when saved as exe

Tags: compilation, exe

I saw the below in a site which says if save the binary code as `.exe`, and executed, it will format the hard disk.

`01001011000111110010010101010101010000011111100000`

Normally when open exe file in notepad, it shows some other thing
[image: EXE in notepad]

Then how the binary code will execute normally without any encoded data?

Comment: This is notepad trying to read the binary data as characters - try using something like Notepad++ and opening the file in HEX mode to get a better idea of what the actual data is.

Comment: And does it work?

Comment: @Pete I didn't checked. If it is a working one, my 1TB Data will go :-(

Comment: @RikLewis Are you sure doing that will not harmful to my system?

Comment: Sorry. I was being facetious. Why would you want code that does this anywhere near your computer?

Comment: I seen this years before while reading an article. So I would like to know how the code is compiling or executing?

Comment: Opening it in notepad won't execute it anymore than opening it in notepad would.  But the binary code looks way too short to actually do anything, if that helps. And if it's binary, it's already been compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to convert the code you provided from `binary` to `text` and the output is

```
K%UA�
```

Which is similar to the screenshot of the notepad file.  It is a compiled code and further converted to binary.

I checked this by going to this link http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/convert-text-to-binary/ , then in the select option, click on **binary to text** and then paste the `binary code` in the above text box.